# Populating an HTML table from an external XML (multiple Values)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I have come across a problem while fetching data from an external XML document with JS. I have been following the w3schools tutorial for AJAX XML so far, but I ran into something I couldn't solve. I have a XML that looks like this:

**THE XML**

```
<root>
 <document-id>
    <author>Tom Riddle</autor>
    <title>abzy</title>
    <year>1995</year>
 </document-id>
 <document-id>
    <author>Tom Riddle</autor>
    <author>Albums Dumbledore</autor>
    <title>abzy</title>
 </document-id>
 <document-id>
    <author>Tom Riddle</autor>
    <year>1995</year>
 </document-id>
</root>
```

I want to access the Data in the above XML and generate a table with all the values. Something I ran into is that if I have for example multiple authors my request will only fetch one author's for each TR element and if there are two it will simply move it down into the next. Is there a way that my code can take all the authors from one document-id and put them into the same td?

*I though of using a for loop for creating the different td elements would that help and how would that have to look?*

**The HTML and JS Code**

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Reading Data from XML Files</h1>
    </header>
    <main>

        <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>

        <table id="demo">

        </table>

    </main>   
    <script>
       function loadDoc() {
          const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onload = function() {
            myFunction(this);
          }
          xhttp.open("GET", "books.xml");
          xhttp.send();
        }
        function myFunction(xml) {
          const xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
          const x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("document-id");
          console.log(x)
          let table="<tr><th>Author</th><th>Title</th><th>Year</th></tr>"; 
          for (let i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
            table += "<tr><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == undefined)?"": x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ) +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == undefined)?"": x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ) +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue == undefined)?"": x[i].getElementsByTagName("year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue ) +
            "</tr>";
          }
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use query selector on the XML documents (responseXML). That works really well if they are not to complex or use namespaces, at which point you might want to look into Xpath.

The standard property for the node content is `textContent`.

```js
// for the example, create the DOM document from a string
const xmlDocument = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(getXMLString(), 'text/xml');

const tbody = document.querySelector('#demo tbody');

// get the document-id elements and put them into an array
const books =  Array.from(xmlDocument.querySelectorAll('document-id'));
books.forEach(
   (book) => {
       // a table row for each element
       const tr = tbody.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
       
       tr
           .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
           .textContent = book.querySelector('title')?.textContent || '';
       tr
           .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
           .textContent = book.querySelector('year')?.textContent || '';
       
       // multiple authors, map nodes to strings and join them
       tr
           .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
           .textContent = Array.from(book.querySelectorAll('author'))
               .map((author) => author.textContent)
               .join(', ');
   }
);

function getXMLString() {
  return  `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
 <document-id>
    <author>Tom Riddle</author>
    <title>One</title>
    <year>1995</year>
 </document-id>
 <document-id>
    <author>Tom Riddle</author>
    <author>Albums Dumbledore</author>
    <title>Two</title>
 </document-id>
 <document-id>
    <author>Tom Riddle</author>
    <year>1995</year>
 </document-id>
</root>`
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="demo">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```